# does table salt dissolve in glycerin

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment

Tell me, does table salt dissolve in glycerin?  And is it possible to increase its solubility?

I have vegetable glycerin with nicotine that I use for vape.  So that nicotine would not be bitter, on the forum I was advised to dissolve salt in it.  But salt dissolves very poorly.  How can I speed up this process?

Comment: Adding water will certainly help with this issue, probably at the cost of introducing other issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bad idea - the salt will deposit on the heating element, possibly risking corrosion and lowering the surface area of the element

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something other than sodium chloride?  Sodium bromide seems to be much more soluble in methanol:

Sodium chloride = [14.9 g/kg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride)

Sodium bromide = [168 g/kg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bromide)

A similar trend would be expected with other alcoholic solvents such as glycerin.

You may also consider lithium chloride.  Lithium salts are more soluble in many polar solvents than heavier Group I salts due to ion pair or covalent molecule formation.  [Lithium chloride](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_chloride) has high solubility in many polar solvents, including over 400 g/kg in methanol and over 240 g/kg in ethanol.  This again suggests that the salt will work well in other alcoholic solvents like glycerin.